# How to add gradle.properties in git-ignore file android?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, gitignore

I am trying to add `gradle.properties` like rest but still changes that files changes are showing in git status.

Is there any other way to add files in `git-ignore` using android studio.

Answer (score 29):

You should use `git rm` to untrack the `gradle.properties` file first.

```
git rm --cached gradle.properties
git commit -m "Remove gradle.properties"
```

Then add the following line to your project `.gitignore` file

```
gradle.properties
```

Commit and push that and any new changes to this file should not be tracked.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you already added this file to repo, and then you want to ignore it. In this case your file exists in Index/Staging area so git is showing it into changed file list.

So you need to remove this file from Index/Staging area, to do so you just need to clean git cache. Execute below command

```
git rm --cached gradle.properties
```

Read more details about [Untrack files already added to git repository based on .gitignore](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way use gitignore plugin and just right click the file which you want to hide and and you'll see add to gitignore option, select it and its done.